# Who in the Grand Palace is Lucia referring to?

Tags: dishonored-2

If you knock out Aramis Stilton and "fix" the timeline, Lucia Pastor can be found in the United Miners office instead of a soup line. She berates you for keeping the Duke in power, then warns that not everyone in the Grand Palace is your enemy. The only person I can think this applies to is

> Armando, the Duke's body double who is open to taking the Duke's place.

**Is there any implication that this person is working for the "resistance", and if not, who else in the Grand Palace could Lucia referring to?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [Dishonored Wiki for Armando](http://dishonored.wikia.com/wiki/Armando):

> He corresponds with Lucia Pastor in the hopes of changing the life conditions of the miners slaving away in the silver mines.

And according to the [Dishonored Wiki for Lucia Pastor](http://dishonored.wikia.com/wiki/Lucia_Pastor):

> She tried as much as contacting Duke Luca Abele through his political double, Armando, to no avail.

It would appear that Armando does wish to assist Lucia Pastor and that this is likely who she is referencing. They carry similar values such as caring for Armando caring for the people of Serkonos and Lucia taking car of the Miners in the silver mines.

Comment: The actual source is the letters between them you can find.